# How do I solve a "dll not found" error when building R Packages?

Tags: r, dll, build, r-package, sap-r3

I am trying to build the RSAP package by Piers Harding (https://github.com/piersharding/RSAP). I followed his instructions for how to build on an R > 3.x.x version. When building the library via...:

```
R CMD INSTALL --build --preclean --clean --no-multiarch -l C:/RSAP RSAP
```

... I get the error "RSAP dll not found".

I am using the 64bit version of R 3.5.1 and latest RTools. I am on Windows 10.

[image]

Comment: Please have a look at the Windows install options in https://github.com/piersharding/RSAP/blob/master/INSTALL

Comment: Hi Roman. Thank you for your comment. This was exactly what I did. Have you managed to get it up running?